# Is there a faster way to copy cell values from one sheet to another if the number of rows and columns keep changing

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet-function

I am trying to make the most general macro to transfer data from one cell to another at the moment I am copy cell by cell to a var and setting the values that way but this really slows things down any ideas?

```
 For i = TableDataRowNum To lastDataRow - 1
        For activeCounter = 0 To colCount
            aCellValue = ServiceTemp.Cells(TableDataRowNum + printCounter, activeCounter + 1).Text
            aSheet.Cells(rowCount + printCounter, activeCounter + 1).value2 = "'" & aCellValue
            aSheet.Cells(rowCount + printCounter, activeCounter + 1).Font.colorIndex = colorValue
        Next
        printCounter = printCounter + 1
        statusBarCounter = statusBarCounter + 1
        If statusBarCounter = 450 Then
             theStatus.ShowStatus "Formatting Data To WorkSheet " & aSheet.Name & " " & printCounter & " Rows Processed"
             statusBarCounter = 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: How large is the dataset? Seems like `Range.Copy()` might do it the same

Comment: the largest possible data set would be 10000 rows

Comment: and wouldn't range.copy require me to hard code the column letter which changes everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not enough reputation to comment, but if you have a continuous range, and you know the starting cell, which you can put in a variable, then you can define the range to copy like below and paste to set destination:

```
Dim luc As Range
Dim src As Range
Dim dest As Range

Set luc = Cells(1, 1)
Set dest = Cells(10, 1)


Set src = Range(luc, luc.End(xlToRight))
Set src = Range(src, src.End(xlDown))

src.Copy

dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

You could wrap this in a sub that takes the left upper corner of the source and target ranges as input.

Comment: Now you can definitely comment :D

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you. I would have only asked whether the formats are essential, and if not, recommended taking the data to array and dumping elsewhere. But Robert already added this answer. Writing to worksheet is staggeringly slow.

Answer (score 1):

It's much faster to work with the data in arrays than the actual cell contents of the table or worksheet.

```
Sub GetArrayData()

'Set the table to a listObject
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = shData.ListObjects("tblTest")

'Create array and fill it with the data of the table
Dim arr As Variant
arr = tbl.DataBodyRange()

Dim row As Long, col As Long

'Loop through the rows/columns of the array if you need to process the data
For row = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For col = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        'Debug.Print arr(row, col)
    Next col
Next row

'Paste data to cell F1
shData.Range("F1:G999") = arr

End Sub
```

This will run almost instantly for 2000 pieces of data and will continue to be fast as you add more data.

Comment: It would be cleaner to define the target range as `shData.Range("F1").Resize(1 To Ubound(arr,1), 1 To Ubound(arr,2).Value = arr `.

Comment: @mpn275 You're completely correct! I shouldn't have gotten lazy at the end.

Comment: And of course you shouldn't have `1 to Ubound(arr,1)` but just `Ubound(arr,1)` in the resize statement.